# How to calculate the hash MD5 of each content of a NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, hash, nsmutablearray

I have this:

```
NSString *string1 = ...;
NSString *string2 = ...;

NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray alloc]inithWithObjects:string1, string2]autorelease];
```

How do I calculate the MD5 hash (or other more appropriate hash) for each content of the `array`, for further comparisons?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method on every string of your array:

```
- (NSString*)md5HexDigest:(NSString*)input {
const char* str = [input UTF8String];
unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CC_MD5(str, strlen(str), result);

NSMutableString *ret = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH*2];
for(int i = 0; i<CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
    [ret appendFormat:@"%02x",result[i]];
}
return ret;
}
```

Do not forget to include:

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>
```